# Getting an error: [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, http-headers

I was working on a blog website using Node.js and express and am not able to figure out the error from which mistake it is popping up. the same is the case with sign-in and sign-up routes.

```
 Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
        at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)
        at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:576:11)
        at ServerResponse.header (D:\blogs-nodejs-mongoodb\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:794:10)
        at ServerResponse.send (D:\blogs-nodejs-mongoodb\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:174:12)
        at done (D:\blogs-nodejs-mongoodb\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1035:10)      
        at tryHandleCache (D:\blogs-nodejs-mongoodb\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:280:5)       
        at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (D:\blogs-nodejs-mongoodb\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:491:10)
        at View.render (D:\blogs-nodejs-mongoodb\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)     
        at tryRender (D:\blogs-nodejs-mongoodb\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:657:10)
        at Function.render (D:\blogs-nodejs-mongoodb\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:609:3)
```

**Below is my signup.ejs code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../auth.css">
</head>
<body>
    <main class="container">
        <%- include('./layout/navbar') %>
        <section class="page flex__center">
            <div class="page__loading flex__center">
                <div class="page__loading__box">
                    <p>Loading.....</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <form class="form form__auth" id="formSignup">
                <h2>Signup Form</h2>
                <div class="form__alert form__error"><p></p></div>
                <div class="form__alert form__success">
                    <p>Success create new account. <a href="/users/signin">Signin now</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="input__control">
                    <label for="username">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Type your username here...">
                    <small class="input__error" id="username__error"></small>
                </div>
                <div class="input__control">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Type your email here...">
                    <small class="input__error" id="email__error"></small>
                </div>
                <div class="input__control">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" id="password">
                    <small class="input__error" id="password__error"></small>
                </div>
                <div class="input__control">
                    <label for="passwordConfirmation">Password Confirmation</label>
                    <input type="password" id="passwordConfirmation">
                    <small class="input__error" id="passwordConfirmation__error"></small>
                </div>
                <div class="btn__group flex__center">
                    <button class="btn" type="submit">Signup Now</button>
                    <button class="btn btn__danger btnClear" type="button">Clear Form</button>
                </div>
                <div class="form__bottom">
                    <p>Already have an account ? <a href="/users/signin">Signin</a></p>
                </div>
            </form>
        </section>
        <%- include('./layout/footer') %>
    </main>

    <script>

        const formSignup = document.getElementById('formSignup')
        const username = document.getElementById('username')
        const email = document.getElementById('email')
        const password = document.getElementById('password')
        const passwordConfirmation = document.getElementById('passwordConfirmation')
        const pageLoading = document.querySelector('.page__loading')
        const formError = document.querySelector('.form__error')
        const formSuccess = document.querySelector('.form__success')

        const domain = 'https://blogs-nodemongoo.herokuapp.com' || 'http://localhost:5000'

        formSignup.addEventListener('submit', async (e) => {
            e.preventDefault()

            if(email.value === '' || password.value === '' || password.value.length < 8 || passwordConfirmation.value === '' || passwordConfirmation.value !== password.value) {
                const errors = showError({username, email, password, passwordConfirmation})
                Object.keys(errors).forEach(err => {
                    document.getElementById(`${err}__error`).innerHTML = errors[err]
                })
            } else {
                const errors = showError({username, email, password, passwordConfirmation})
                Object.keys(errors).forEach(err => {
                    document.getElementById(`${err}__error`).innerHTML = ''
                })
                try {
                    const values = {
                        username: username.value,
                        email: email.value,
                        password: password.value
                    }
                    pageLoading.style.display = 'flex'
                    const res = await fetch(`${domain}/users/signup`, {
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                        },
                        body: JSON.stringify(values)
                    })
                    const data = await res.json()
                    if(data.message) {
                        pageLoading.style.display = 'none'
                        formSuccess.style.display = 'block'
                        formError.style.display = 'none'
                        resetForm()
                    } else {
                        throw Error(data.error)
                    }
                } catch (error) {
                    pageLoading.style.display = 'none'
                    formError.style.display = 'block'
                    document.querySelector('.form__error p').innerHTML = error.message
                    formSuccess.style.display = 'none'
                }
            }
        })

        function resetForm() {
            username.value = ''
            email.value = ''
            password.value = ''
            passwordConfirmation.value = ''
        }

        document.querySelector('.btnClear').addEventListener('click', () => {
            resetForm()
            formError.style.display = 'none'
            formSuccess.style.display = 'none'
            const errors = showError({username, email, password, passwordConfirmation})
            Object.keys(errors).forEach(err => {
                document.getElementById(`${err}__error`).innerHTML = ''
            })
        })


        function showError(values) {
            let errors = {
                username: '',
                email: '',
                password: '',
                passwordConfirmation: ''
            }
            if(values.username.value === '') {
                errors.username = 'Please fill the username input'
            }
            if(values.email.value === '') {
                errors.email = 'Please fill the email input'
            }
            if(values.password.value === '') {
                errors.password = 'Please fill the password input'
            } 
            if(values.password.value && values.password.value.length < 8) {
                errors.password = 'Minimum password 8 character or more'
            }
            if(values.passwordConfirmation.value !== values.password.value) {
                errors.passwordConfirmation = 'Password confirmation not match'
            }
            if(values.passwordConfirmation.value === '') {
                errors.passwordConfirmation = 'Please fill the password confirmation input'
            }
            return errors
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have been googling it for 2 hours, but have not been able to get the mistake. Any help is highly appreciated!!

EDIT: I have attached my authentication routes and server side code.

**Below is my authRoute.js code**

```
const express = require('express')
const {
    signinPost,
    signupPost
} = require('../controllers/authController')
const { requireAuth } = require('../middleware/authMiddleware')
const router = express.Router()

router.get('/users/signin', requireAuth, (req, res) => res.render('signin', {title: 'Signin Page'}))
router.get('/users/signup', requireAuth, (req, res) => res.render('signup', {title: 'Signup Page'}))
router.get('/users/signout', (req, res) => {
    res.clearCookie('userLogin')
    res.status(200).json({
        message: 'Success signout'
    })
})

router.post('/users/signin', async (req, res) => await signinPost(req, res))
router.post('/users/signup', async (req, res) => await signupPost(req, res))

module.exports = router
```

**and the below is the server-side code**

```
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const appRoute = require('./routes/appRoute')
const dashboardRoute = require('./routes/dashboardRoute')
const authRoute = require('./routes/authRoute')
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const { currentUser } = require('./middleware/authMiddleware')
require('dotenv').config({path: './config/config.env'})

const app = express()

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGOODB_URI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
}).then(() => {
    app.listen( process.env.PORT || 5000, () => console.log('Connected to server'))
}).catch(() => console.log('Failed connect to database'))

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cookieParser())
app.get('*', currentUser)
app.use(dashboardRoute)
app.use(appRoute)
app.use(authRoute)
app.get('*', (req, res) => res.render('404', { title: 'Page Not Found'}))
```

**Below I have attached the authController.js code**

```
const Users = require('../models/users')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

// 1 hour
const maxAge = 60 * 60 * 24
const createToken = (id) => {
    return jwt.sign({id}, 'secret-app-token', {
        expiresIn: maxAge
    })
}

const signinPost = async(req, res) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body
    try {
        const user = await Users.signin(email, password)
        const token = createToken(user.id)
        res.cookie('userLogin', token, { maxAge: maxAge * 1000})
        res.status(200).json({
            message: 'Success login app',
            user
        })
    } catch(error) {
        res.status(400).json({
            error: error.message
        })
    }
}
const signupPost = async (req, res) => {
    const { username, email, password } = req.body
    try {
        await Users.create({username, email, password})
        res.status(201).json({
            message: 'Success create new account'
        })
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({
            error: error.message
        })    
    }
}


module.exports = {
    signinPost,
    signupPost
}
```

**and authmiddleware code also below**

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const Users = require('../models/users')


const requireAuth = (req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.cookies?.userLogin
    if(token) {
        if(req.url === '/users/signin' || req.url === '/users/signup') {
            res.redirect('/')
            next()
        } else {
            jwt.verify(token, 'secret-app-token', (err, decodedToken) => {
                if(err) {
                    res.redirect('/users/signin')
                    next()
                } else {
                    next()
                }
            })
        }
    } else {
        if(req.url === '/users/signin' || req.url === '/users/signup') {
            next()
        } else {
            res.redirect('/users/signin')
            next()
        }
    }
}


const currentUser = async (req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.cookies?.userLogin

    if(token) {
        jwt.verify(token, 'secret-app-token', async (err, decodedToken) => {
            if(err) {
                res.locals.currentUser = null
                next()
            } else {
                const currentUser = await Users.findById(decodedToken.id)
                res.locals.currentUser = {
                    id: currentUser._id,
                    email: currentUser.email,
                    username: currentUser.username
                }
                next()
            }
        })
    } else {
        res.locals.currentUser = null
        next()
    }
}


module.exports = {
    requireAuth,
    currentUser
}
```

I have tried debugging them, but am still not able to get the mistake.

Any help would be much welcomed!!

Comment: The error comes from your server-side code, please share that.

Comment: Hey @HeikoTheißen, thank you so much for the reply. I have added the relevant code, and the middleware too.

Comment: `res.redirect(...)` already completes the response and must not be followed by `next()`, because that invokes subsequent middlewares, which produces a second response, leading to the observed error.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @HeikoTheißen. It worked!! Would keep that in mind next time!!